# when will Fragment.mActivity field be written?

Tags: android, android-fragments

In the source code of `Fragment`, there is a field called `mActivity`:

```
package android.app;
public class Fragment implements ComponentCallbacks2, OnCreateContextMenuListener {

    // Activity this fragment is attached to.
    Activity mActivity;
```

In order to find where this field is written, I've tried as follow:

1. I've checked the source code of `Fragment`, and I found only one writing behavior in `Fragment.initState()` method:

   ```
   mActivity = null;
   ```

   But `Fragment` uses `mActivity` very frequently, there must be somewhere the field is written.
2. The access of `mActivity` is `default`, so maybe there is other classes who will write this field. Then I checked the usage of `Fragment` class, but nothing I found relative to the writing behavior of this field.
3. Don't know **what to do next**, maybe some special processes in Android?

Could anyone tell me whether the way above is correct to find answers to such questions?
Please give me some advice on finding usage of a class/field/method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a `Fragment`, but `FragmentManager` actually manages `mActivity` field. Since it is not private, any package-local class can access it.

Check the [`FragmentManager.moveToState()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java#FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState%28android.support.v4.app.Fragment%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%2Cboolean%29) method, [line 900](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java#900) for support `FragmentManager`
Check the [`FragmentManager.moveToState()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/app/FragmentManager.java#FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState%28android.app.Fragment%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%2Cboolean%29) method, [line 848](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/app/FragmentManager.java#848) for `android.app.FragmentManager`

Comment: Have you checked ever occurrence of `Fragment` class? If not, could you please tell me how you quickly find the line modified the field? Thanks!

Comment: You linked to the wrong class. The question was about `android.app`, not support v4 library

Comment: @cricket_007, I've used `find usages` in Android Studio for finding accessions to `Fragment.mActivity`. As for wrong class - it's the same for `android.app.FragmentManager`. The only difference is in line number: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/app/FragmentManager.java#848

Comment: @VladMatvienko `find usages` could not locate the `f.mActivity` in `FragmentManager` class. Cause the platform source code `Fragment.java`can not be totally compiled, so the  `Fragment` class will not be resolved. How did you solve this?

Comment: @JY0284, I editted find options to search in library sources, and now it searches in android sources as well

Comment: I changed the option too. But the source code of `FragmentManager` contains lots of errors, the critical one is that it cannot resolve `Fragment` class in the line *f.activity*, which means the IDE won't find the usage here.

Comment: @JY0284, I actually searched through a android support FragmentManager sources, and find same methods in GrepCode source of android.app.Fragmentmanager

Comment: @VladMatvienko Got it, Thanks!